# Monitor Spark Jobs in real time

Tags: javascript, python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I want to monitor Spark Jobs in real time

For that I have fetch data from [Spark Monitoring](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) REST API and display in visualizations. One solution is to Poll the API at every 1 second. But I want to do it without polling.

Can we do something like [Webhook](https://docs.api.ai/docs/webhook).

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: What is your use case , asking because spark has its own webUI , if you are running on yarn, then yarn also has its own webUI.

Comment: @Pushkr I have to make a Jupyter notebook plugin, which on submission of Spark Job, displays the details in real time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Webhook but i think you can use [SparkListener](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-SparkListener.html) to push spark scheduler events in real time to your backend application.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  SparkListener are available in Scala. I am not aware whether they are available in Pyspark.